# How to add library/jar files in java application when deployed in solaris server?

Tags: java, glassfish, solaris

I have developed a java application which run's perfectly in local server. But When I upload it on a solaris server it gives the error were not found where indicated: lib/ojdbc6.jar lib/jstl-1.2.jar lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar ; ignoring and continuing|#]

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks
Enamul

Comment: Is it a webapp or a java application ? How is it packaged ? How do you launch it ?

Comment: It's a java application. I deployed the myapp.jar on glassfish server

Comment: And it runs perfectly in Glassfish on your own computer?

Comment: I'm afraid you are confusing java applications which are standalone and only requiring a JVM/JDK to run and Java EE applications which require an application server to run. You do not deploy jar files on an application server, you deploy war or ear files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that your application is looking for these jars in the classpath and cannot find them, you have two options:

1. copy these jars into the Glassfish libs - this is the easiest option, but note that this will cause all other applications running on the server to recognize these jars as well. Usually it is not a problem but it might be if there are other applications that are working with other versions of these jars.
2. Pack your jar with all its dependencies.